# requests.get and parse response to json

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

As the title, I want "requests.get and parse response to json". Here are the ways I have tried to do this

1. Using request().json()

```
requests.get(url = "https://ac.dict.naver.com/linedictweb/ac?q=%E6%B5%B7&st=010&r_lt=000&q_enc=UTF-8&r_format=json&r_enc=UTF-8&_t=1599558293560&_callback=jQuery111104358648061767311_1599558261058&_=1599558261060",verify = True).json()
 =>Result: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

2.Another Way

```
r = requests.get(url = "https://ac.dict.naver.com/linedictweb/ac?q=%E6%B5%B7&st=010&r_lt=000&q_enc=UTF-8&r_format=json&r_enc=UTF-8&_t=1599558293560&_callback=jQuery111104358648061767311_1599558261058&_=1599558261060",verify = True)
json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
=> RESULT: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Data Json [here](https://anotepad.com/notes/t7nfqiq7):

Help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: The response isn't valid JSON; it's JSON wrapped in something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery callback is wrapping the output. Get rid of the callback parameter in the url and you will get valid json:

```py
r = requests.get(url = "https://ac.dict.naver.com/linedictweb/ac?q=%E6%B5%B7&st=010&r_lt=000&q_enc=UTF-8&r_format=json&r_enc=UTF-8&_t=1599558293560",verify = True)


r.json()
{
  "query": [
    "\u6d77"
  ],
  "items": [
    [],
    [
      [
        [
          "zh"
        ],
        [
          "597527adbb7248c3ae80d60b9acd7160"
        ],
        [
          "\u6d77"
        ],
        [
          " ocean; extra large"
        ], 
    ...
}
```

Comment: The error above was obvious but I didn't realize it. I just removed "_callback = jQueryxxx" from the url. Maybe I was too nervous. Thank you so much.